# How to move IIS settings for 1 website to another computer?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2019

I have access to an IIS server (SvrA) that hosts multiple sites.

I am setting up an UAT environment on another server (SvrB) into which I want to deploy one of the above sites. I have copied the website folder from SvrA and pasted it on SvrB.

1. The folder contains web.config which I assume will automatically configure the IIS settings for the website?
2. Are there any other settings that I need to manually note down to copy?
3. Is there an easier way to copy the settings (for example: export to txt file) rather than manually noting down each setting?

Upon further research it looks like there are 3 options to copy the settings:

1. Web deploy (https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy)
2. Using export functionality in the IIS `Shared configuration` tab (https://www.itnota.com/migrate-iis-websites-to-different-server/)
3. Using `AppCmd.exe` (refer to same link as above)

Is it correct that app pool and website settings is everything? or is there any other setting beyond the app pool and website settings?

Comment: Shared configuration is not considered a way to move a site to another server, but mirror the entire web server. So you should exclude it from your option list. Besides, more and more users are moving to container based deployment even for Windows based web apps, and you should evaluate that too.

Comment: Is it correct that app pool and website settings is everything? or is there any other setting beyond the app pool and website settings?

Comment: By `Shared configuration` I meant the `export` functionality in the IIS shared configuration  tab. I have updated this into my question. Is this not an option?

Comment: There are far too many things beyond IIS configuration. Windows HTTP API settings/certificates are just a few items commonly involved. That's also why containers are popular because they are self-contained.

Comment: Even the export/import from shared configuration is an unnecessary option as it exports the settings for entire IIS server, while you just need a single site.

Comment: Ok so web deploy or AppCmd is the way ahead?

Comment: Nope. Containers are the ultimate.

Comment: So currently there is no container on source IIS how do I use container?

Comment: Web deploy is the best choice.  You don't have to care about application pools or anything else, just export and import the website to another IIS as you would with web deploy. All configuration web deploy will do it for you.